# Cluster analysis in matlab or python - k-means clustering on three dimensional data

Tags: 3d, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have 3dimensional data. So for 705 frequencies i have 24*2 data. 24 rows represent hours and columns represent mean and coefficient of variance. This 24*2*705 matrix data.

I would like to perform k-means on this data.

How should i do this either in matlab or python?

Any suggestions.

Vaishali

Answer (score 0):

K-means does not correlated or mix components. The results are invariant to any permutation of axes.

Hence it is safe to reshaoe your data into a n.p format as used by k-means.

The bigger question is whether SSR is the right objective for your *problem*. Are you solving the right problem, or just using k-means because it is cool.